# Dynamic ActionLink from JsonResult?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an MVC3 application. I have some logic in my view that I want to move to my controller. It dynamically displays an ActionLink depending on certain aspects of the model. The linkText and the actionName parameters for Html.ActionLink are the only thing that can differ. I added a method to my controller that would return a JsonResult with strings for linkText and actionName:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult GetActionButton(int id)
{
    string action = null;
    string text = null;

    // Snipped stuff that sets action and text

    return Json(new
    {
        buttonAction = action,
        buttonText = text
    });
}
```

Where could I call this method to create the link using the results?

Comment: is this method being called through ajax, or used server-side in a view, or both?

Comment: @MrOBrian - that's what I'm trying to figure out - not sure where the right place to call it is to be able to reference its results when creating the link.

Comment: Well, since it's a JsonResult, I would assume you are calling it through ajax from the client, but you mentioned wanting to move some logic from the view to the controller for Html.ActionLink, which would be on the server. If the links are different depending on the model, you'll likely want to do it all server-side and not use json, but if the links change based on something that happens on the client then you'll want to use ajax to return a json result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For link generation from controller look at [UrlHelper Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492942%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), it's better to use `Action` for receiving normal url. On client with jquery you can create link like:

```
$('<a>').attr('href', data.buttonAction).text(data.buttonText)
```

Comment: This is the best route IMO, it is what I've used before when I've needed the "rendered" URL in code.

Answer (score 1):

Where are the multiple ID's coming from, I'm guessing in the view model?

Perhaps using jQuery/AJAX on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  // AJAX call to GetActionButton for each enumeration over the ID's in the view model
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I thiink you want an HTML Helper.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString MyActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        string actionLinkHtml = string.Format("<a href=\"/{0}/{1}\">{2}</a>", controllerName, actionName, linkText);
        return new MvcHtmlString(actionLinkHtml);
    }
```

Of course there will be more code to set your variables, and your parameters will probably just be the same int ID that you have above, but this is the basic idea.

Then in view just use :

```
    @Html.MyActionLink("link text", "action", "ctrlr")
```